# Computer crashed while encrypting drive with BitLocker - Drive is now locked

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

Running Windows 10 Pro, I started encrypting an external drive yesterday. However, during the process my PC completely froze and I was forced to hard-reset the computer, presumably before the encryption process finished.

After rebooting, the drive now shows as locked. When I attempt to unlock it, I get shown a message that: "The BitLocker encryption on this drive isn’t compatible with your version of Windows", despite it being the same OS I ran last night. I attempted to run Windows Update, rebooted after, but that yields the same results.

I ran `manage-bde -status`, which recognizes the drive showing:

```
Size: Unknown GB
Bitlocker version: None
Conversion Status: Unknown
Percentage Encrypted: Unknown%
ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070057): The parameter is incorrect
```

I also tried running `manage-bde -unlock F: -RecoveryKey "<path-to-file-containing-recoverykey"`, which results in:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while attempting to read the key from disk
```

Both `manage-bde -off F:` and `manage-bde -resume F:` yield:

```
ERROR: The operation cannot be performed because the volume is locked
```

When attempting to run it and getting prompted for a pw, it states:

```
ERROR: The password failed to unlock volume F:
```

(I tried the actual password and one while CAPS lock was on to ensure it wasn't that).

Lastly, I tried running `manage-bde -protectors -get F:` to try and figure out whether any protectors were in place. However, the response from that was:

```
ERROR: No key protectors found
```

I'm fresh out of ideas at this point, but hope someone might have a way for me to recover my data.

Comment: You are out of luck, while BitLocker initial encryption processes can be paused, it must be done gracefully.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can recover anything on the disk, or is a full format all that's left to try?

Comment: You do not have a disk image to restore, made before encryption?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Unfortunately not. I didn't anticipate the crash.

Comment: @SchmitzIT - I am not sure, how I can be clearer, by saying "You are out of luck",

Answer (score 2):

Bad news : BitLocker encrypted volumes cannot be recovered if
the encryption process is interrupted by a crash.

Your disk is lost : Format it to be able to use.
All encrypted data is likely lost.

If you had on the disk important data without backup, you could
try some BitLocker recovery products. However, the chances are slim
even if you have kept the recovery key.

I can't recommend a good BitLocker recovery product, and the best
ones are payware.